# Printing behavior using fork() in C

Tags: c, linux, fork

I started learning about forks, but I don't understand why this prints 4. More specifically I don't understand when the child process will finish and the parent process will exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i, status;
    int x =1;
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int pid = fork();
        x++;
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(&status);
            x--;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    printf ("x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried a diagram to understand it better

[Click here to see the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koGC3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a chain of `fork()`s in which only the last child will be alive after the `for` loop. At each iteration, `x` is increased as such:

```
original process
x = 1
  |
fork() --> child1
  |          |
x++        x++ (x==2)
parent     fork() --> child2
waits        |          |
for        x++        x++ (x==3)
child1     child1     fork() --> child3
  |        waits        |          |
  |        for        x++        x++ (x==4)
  |        child2     child2       |
  |          |        waits        |
  |          |        for          |
  |          |        child3       |
  |          |          |          |
  |          |          |          |
  |          |          |        printf ("x = %d\n", x);
  |          |          |        return 0;
  |          |        x--
  |          |        exit
  |        x--
  |        exit
x--
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The initial process (670743) forks a child (670744) which subsequently increments it's copy of `x`.  It doesn't matter what the parent does to it's copy of `x` before it eventually exits (after a child exits).

In the next iteration the first child is now the parent with a copy of an increment value of `x` (now 2).  It forks another child (670745) and the process repeat till last child (670746) exists the loop and prints `x = 4`.

I modified your code as follows to demonstrate this (also added the missing headers for Linux, reduced scope of `i` and eliminated the unused `status` variable):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("pid=%jd, x=%d, i=%d\n", (intmax_t) getpid(), x, i);
        int pid = fork();
        x++;
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(&(int) { 0 });
            x--;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    printf("pid=%jd, x=%d\n", (intmax_t) getpid(), x);
}
```

which shows it's the last child process that prints out `x`:

```
pid=670743, x=1, i=0
pid=670744, x=2, i=1
pid=670745, x=3, i=2
pid=670746, x=4
```